# How to prevent context switch in a critical section

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class main {
    final static Object lock= new Object();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {

            System.out.println("-------");
            finish finished = new finish(false);
            ArrayList<Boolean> arr = new ArrayList<>();

            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Is setting");
                finished.setFinished(true);

            });


            t1.start();
            synchronized (lock){
                if (finished.isFinished == false) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " Is adding");
                    arr.add(new Boolean(finished.isFinished));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Done");
                }
            }


            System.out.println("The length of array is " + arr.size());
            if (arr.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("The val of array is " + arr.get(0));
            }
        }
    }
}

class finish {
    public boolean isFinished = false;

    public finish(boolean finished) {
        this.isFinished = finished;
    }

    public void setFinished(boolean finished) {
        this.isFinished = finished;

    }

}
```

I am expecting to get the following output :

*The length of array is 1 

The val of array is false*

or

*Done*

It is the case most of the times.
But sometimes the output is :

*The length of array is 1 

The val of array is true*

It means, that there was a context switch in the critical section.
I have tried to synchronized the code on an object, but it did not help.
It is a classical synchronization problem, I but was not able to solve it.
Maybe I should use atomic objects, but I have no idea how would they help in this case.
Or perhaps I am to harsh with java, and I should not test it in a for loop? I am running this example on a Linux OS.
I think my synchronization does not make sense. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Show us your attempt at synchronizing.

Comment: You are not synchronizing both threads therefore you cannot guarantee the result you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all clear what your example code is trying to do, but if you want to wait for the thread to finish, use `t1.join()` and deal with the `InterruptedException` that this throws. Also, `finished` should be an `AtomicBoolean` if you're going to use it in more than one thread.

But all in all, the code is pretty problematic, and doesn't reflect whatever real-life scenario you're trying to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are reading the same variable twice, which allows for the possibility it can be changed. The simplest solution is to read it just once.

```
boolean isFinished = finished.isFinished;
if (isFinished) {
    System.out.println("Done");
} else {
    System.out.println(t1 + " Is adding");
    arr.add(isFinished);
}
```